# Connect Frontend and Backend in Venia PWA Setup

Tags: magento2.4.5, pwa, component, venia, react-js

We have Magento PWA Venia Setup.

Now We installed the Extension downloaded from Commerce Marketplace.

The Extension installed fine and now we can see configuration in backend.

**Requirement**

Now How we can connect the extension to Frontend , so that we need to display the information in frontend.

Comment: You have installed an extension that is PWA-supported? or which type of extension did you purchase?

Comment: @RohitGohel please check :  https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/firework-firework.html

Comment: OKay i have checked now tell me what is the issue you have faced into this extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have post my answer after talking with you please create these files and add them to the directory

src > components > HomePage > components > FierWork.js

```
import React from "react";
import HeadTitle from './HeadTitle';

const FireWork = () => {
    return(
        <div class="fw_story_wrapper">
            <HeadTitle title={'Shop By Look'} textAlign={'center'} />
            <script async src='//asset.fwcdn3.com/js/storyblock.js'></script>
            <fw-storyblock branding="false"  channel="glow" playlist="kj43j2" autoplay="true"></fw-storyblock>
            <br/>
            <script async src="//asset.fwcdn3.com/js/embed-feed.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
            <fw-embed-feed channel="glow" playlist="kj43j2" ui_border_style="hard"></fw-embed-feed>
        </div>
    );
}

export default FireWork;
```

after that add this code to the homepage.js file after the SpotLight code line no. 17

```
const FireWork = React.lazy(() => import('./components/FireWork'));
```

now add this code after the Sportlight code homepage.js file line no. 130

```
'fierwork': FireWork,
```

Please follow this way and run the command into the terminal

```
yarn run build
```

If this solution works for you so please accept my solution and give an upvote.
Thanks.

Comment: [Thanks you joined in chat & helped me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25332/magento-chat)